# multiple div height same as width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a responsive blocks with jQuery. I have a 2 cube blocks, but they are different in width. I write down a little lines, to make them responsive, but now the second takes first `div` height and changing on resize. In this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95poy51w/1/)** you can see it when you resizing a window width.

I wanted, that the different cubes resizing different and make cube form.

There's also my code

```
function cube(){
    var divWidth = $('.cube').width(); 
    $('.cube').height(divWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.each()` function for this. check snippet below

```js
cube();
$(window).resize(cube);

function cube() {
    $('.cube').each(function() {
    $(this).height($(this).width());
  }); 
    
}
```

```css
.block1 {
  background: red;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block2 {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block1  cube"></div>
<br/>
<div class="block2 cube"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! it helped and now its working :) I accept your answer, when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a forEach to loop through the divs

```
cube();

$(window).resize(cube);

function cube(){
$('.cube').each(function(){
        var divWidth = $(this).width(); 
    $(this).height(divWidth);
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Updated Fiddle Here [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95poy51w/6/)

```
<div class="block1  cube"></div>
<br/>
<div class="block2 cube"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.block1{


background:red;
  width:100%;

}

.block2{
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
}
```

Js :

```
$(window).resize(function(cube){
cube();
function cube(){
    var divWidth = $('.cube').width(); 
    $('.cube').height(divWidth);
    }

});
```